# Sveltekit: how to disable the warning "Loading [url] using `window.fetch`. For best results, use the `fetch` that is passed to your `load` function"

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I use a package that makes a request on page load (it is not my own code), and always triggers this warning message.

It also seems that currently the warning [is triggering erroneously](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/7992).

How can I suppress this warning ? *(I am using Sveltekit 1.13.0)*

Comment: What happens if you do `window.fetch = fetch` (the second fetch is the one provided by the load function) before calling the package code?